# I want to implent some question randomly but always a new one

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to create a game with a qestion and the question is randomly but there is a lot of repetition of questions. I want that the question can appear only once. There is the code of all activity for my game

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView mQuestionTextViewVe;
    private QuestionBankVe mQuestionBankVe;
    private QuestionVeriter mCurrentQuestionVe;
    private Button mbackButton;
    private ArrayList<String> arrayList;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_veriter);

        System.out.println("veriterActivity::onCreate()");

        mQuestionBankVe = this.generateQuestions();

        mQuestionTextViewVe = findViewById(R.id.activity_veriter_question_text);

        mCurrentQuestionVe = mQuestionBankVe.getQuestion();
        this.displayQuestion(mCurrentQuestionVe);

    private void displayQuestion(final QuestionVeriter question) {
        mQuestionTextViewVe.setText(question.getQuestion());
    }

    private QuestionBankVe generateQuestions() {
        QuestionVeriter question1 = new QuestionVeriter("Question");
        QuestionVeriter question2 = new QuestionVeriter("Question");
        QuestionVeriter question3 = new QuestionVeriter("Question");

        return new QuestionBankVe(Arrays.asList( question1,
        question2
        question3

        ));
    }
}
```

```
public class QuestionBankVe {

        private List<QuestionVeriter> mQuestionListVe;
        private int mNextQuestionIndexVe;

        public QuestionBankVe(List<QuestionVeriter> questionListVe) {
            mQuestionListVe = questionListVe;

            // Shuffle the question list
            Collections.shuffle(mQuestionListVe);

            mNextQuestionIndexVe = 0;
        }

        public QuestionVeriter getQuestion() {
            // Ensure we loop over the questions
            if (mNextQuestionIndexVe == mQuestionListVe.size()) {
                mNextQuestionIndexVe = 0;
            }

            // Please note the post-incrementation
            return mQuestionListVe.get(mNextQuestionIndexVe++);
        }
    }
```

```
public class QuestionVeriter {

    private String mQuestionVe;



    public QuestionVeriter(String question) {
        this.setQuestion(question);
    }


    public String getQuestion() {
        return mQuestionVe;
    }

    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        mQuestionVe = question;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Question{" +
                "mQuestion='" + mQuestionVe + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: You're already shuffling the `mQuestionListVe` List. Instead of calling get, call `remove()` on this list to get each unique question in a random order, and only once. That looks to be all that you have to do.

Comment: Where do I have to add the remove() ? Hovercraft ?

Comment: I don't know how to do and  the soluton is true